# several voice commands from Voice

Tags: c#

what am I doing wrong?

So I say "speak lower" I want the volume to lower and vice versa.

```
int amp = 80;

if (speech.Contains("speak"))
{
    if (speech.Contains("louder"))
    {
        MARVIN.Volume = amp - 10;
        amp = MARVIN.Volume;
        MARVIN.Speak("Volume is lower");
    }
    else if (speech.Contains(" louder"))
    {
        MARVIN.Volume = amp + 10;
        amp = MARVIN.Volume;
        MARVIN.Speak("Volume is louder");
    }
    else
    {
        MARVIN.Speak("Volume value is not defined sir");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe your problem. What is not working, or what do you expect to happen that does not happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean `lower` here?

```
if (speech.Contains("lower"))
{
    MARVIN.Volume = amp - 10;
    amp = MARVIN.Volume;
    MARVIN.Speak("Volume is lower");
}
```

You said 'so I i say "speak lower"' but in if you check for `louder`

Comment: There is also a blank before one of the `" louder"` strings.

Answer (score 0):

I would split the string in order to get the keywords out.

```
int amp = 80;

string[] commands = speech.Split(' ');    

if (commands[0] == "speak")
{
    switch (commands[1])
    {
        case "lower":
        {
            MARVIN.Volume = amp - 10;
            amp = MARVIN.Volume;
            MARVIN.Speak("Volume is lower");

            break;
        }
        case "louder":
        {
            MARVIN.Volume = amp + 10;
            amp = MARVIN.Volume;
            MARVIN.Speak("Volume is louder");

            break;
        }
    }
}
```